# Convert JSON String to C# Object For Complex JSON String

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I am trying to convert JSON string to C# Object, but I am getting null values

Below is the JSON string I have

```
[
    {
        "extraction_method": "stream",
        "top": 0.0,
        "left": 0.0,
        "width": 559.0,
        "height": 732.2100219726562,
        "data": [[
                {
                    "top": 0.0,
                    "left": 0.0,
                    "width": 0.0,
                    "height": 0.0,
                    "text": ""
                },
                {
                    "top": 96.36,
                    "left": 129.27,
                    "width": 102.97900390625,
                    "height": 6.550000190734863,
                    "text": "Sample"
                },
                {
                    "top": 96.35,
                    "left": 311.0,
                    "width": 27.188995361328125,
                    "height": 6.550000190734863,
                    "text": "PT"
                },
                {
                    "top": 96.35,
                    "left": 361.0,
                    "width": 41.248992919921875,
                    "height": 6.550000190734863,
                    "text": "HT"
                },
                {
                    "top": 96.36,
                    "left": 432.11,
                    "width": 28.141387939453125,
                    "height": 6.550000190734863,
                    "text": "RT."
                },
                {
                    "top": 96.36,
                    "left": 480.88,
                    "width": 29.64898681640625,
                    "height": 6.550000190734863,
                    "text": "LT."
                },
                {
                    "top": 96.36,
                    "left": 522.33,
                    "width": 36.660003662109375,
                    "height": 6.550000190734863,
                    "text": "MT"
                }
            ], [
                {
                    "top": 727.57,
                    "left": 75.24,
                    "width": 14.902000427246094,
                    "height": 4.619999885559082,
                    "text": "Tee"
                },
                {
                    "top": 0.0,
                    "left": 0.0,
                    "width": 0.0,
                    "height": 0.0,
                    "text": ""
                },
                {
                    "top": 727.57,
                    "left": 315.0,
                    "width": 14.00201416015625,
                    "height": 4.619999885559082,
                    "text": "IO."
                },
                {
                    "top": 727.59,
                    "left": 381.43,
                    "width": 16.6820068359375,
                    "height": 4.619999885559082,
                    "text": "1.10"
                },
                {
                    "top": 727.59,
                    "left": 434.53,
                    "width": 25.582000732421875,
                    "height": 4.619999885559082,
                    "text": "30.00"
                },
                {
                    "top": 727.59,
                    "left": 488.98,
                    "width": 21.131988525390625,
                    "height": 4.619999885559082,
                    "text": "8.00"
                },
                {
                    "top": 727.59,
                    "left": 534.53,
                    "width": 24.469959259033203,
                    "height": 4.619999885559082,
                    "text": "18.00"
                }
            ]],
        "spec_index": 0
    }
]
```

And the classes for JSON object

```
public class JsonHelper
{
    string top { get; set; }
    string left { get; set; }
    string width { get; set; }
    string height { get; set; }
    string text { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string extraction_method { get; set; }
    public double top { get; set; }
    public double left { get; set; }
    public double width { get; set; }
    public double height { get; set; }
    public List<List<JsonHelper>> data { get; set; }
    public int spec_index { get; set; }
}
```

And below code is used to get the object

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"SamplePDF.json"))
        {
            string json = r.ReadToEnd();
            List<RootObject> items = 
                    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);
        }
```

But I am getting, null values in the object as below(open image in new tab if image is not displayed below),

Let me know on the same, thanks

[image]

Comment: @John Thanks, "JSONHelper" properties were not accessible.Silly Me!!!

Answer (score 1):

Hadn't made the below properties accessible, below are the changes. Thanks to @John.

```
public class JsonHelper
{
    string top { get; set; }
    string left { get; set; }
    string width { get; set; }
    string height { get; set; }
    string text { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may give default value to them like :

```
public int X { get; set; } = 0;
public string Y { get; set; } = "";
```

Comment: How would this fix the problem?

Comment: img cannot be displayed so i got it wrong, thought deserialization was the problem

Answer (score -1):

Your class looks like not match the format of JSON string, try this

1. add a new class
2. remove the part of class "public class Class1{}"
3. copy the JSON string
4. Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON as Classes

then JSON.Net will match the Object and JSON string

I have tried your sample JSON string and the object is created by step 4 like this

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
}

public class Class1
{
    public string extraction_method { get; set; }
    public float top { get; set; }
    public float left { get; set; }
    public float width { get; set; }
    public float height { get; set; }
    public Datum[][] data { get; set; }
    public int spec_index { get; set; }
}

public class Datum
{
    public float top { get; set; }
    public float left { get; set; }
    public float width { get; set; }
    public float height { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
}
```